# Is it possible to exclude hidden rows when searching for duplicates in Excel?

Tags: excel, vba, big-o, quadratic

I am working on a procedure in Excel using VBA that highlights duplicate rows. The procedure evaluates the result of the worksheet function sumproduct to determine if the row has duplicates.

The evaluated formula ends up looking like this:

```
SUMPRODUCT(--(A1:A10 = A1), --(B1:B10 = B1), --(C1:C10 = C1))
```

So far the procedure works great, but I need it to disregard hidden rows and columns from the evaluation. I can skip over hidden rows in columns in my loops using `Range.Hidden = False`, but I haven't figured out a way to exclude hidden rows and columns from SUMPRODUCT.

I also tried iterating through every row twice using two nested loops and just comparing values two rows at a time, but that resulted in N-squared, or O(n<sup>2</sup>), iterations, so I gave up on that method.

Is there a way to coerce SUMPRODUCT into ignoring hidden rows, as is possible with the spreadsheet formula SUBTOTAL?

Here is what I have so far using `Evaluate(SUMPRODUCT)`: Thanks!

```
Private Sub ShowDuplicateRows()

    Dim lngRow As Long
    Dim lngColumn As Long
    Dim strFormula As String

    With Selection

        For lngRow = 1 To .Rows.Count
            If Not .Rows(lngRow).Hidden Then

                strFormula = "SUMPRODUCT("
                For lngColumn = 1 To .Columns.Count
                    If Not .Columns(lngColumn).Hidden Then
                        If strFormula <> "SUMPRODUCT(" Then
                            strFormula = strFormula & ", "
                        End If
                        strFormula = strFormula _
                        & "--(" & .Columns(lngColumn).Address _
                        & " = " & .Cells(lngRow, lngColumn).Address & ")"
                    End If
                Next
                strFormula = strFormula & ")"

                If Evaluate(strFormula) > 1 Then
                    .Rows(lngRow).Font.Color = RGB(255, 0, 0)
                End If

            End If
        Next lngRow

    End With

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The RowHeight/Hidden property is not exposed to any formula. The solution will have to be in VBA. One way to accomplish this is to create a User Defined Formula (UDF) that does what you want it to, then just use it in your sumproduct formula.

```
Public Function IsVisible(ByVal rng As Excel.Range) As Variant
    Dim varRtnVal As Variant
    Dim lRow As Long, lCol As Long
    Dim ws As Excel.Worksheet
    ReDim varRtnVal(1 To rng.Rows.Count, 1 To rng.Columns.Count)
    For lRow = 1& To rng.Rows.Count
        For lCol = 1& To rng.Columns.Count
            varRtnVal(lRow, lCol) = CDbl(-(rng.Cells(lRow, lCol).RowHeight > 0&))
        Next
    Next
    IsVisible = varRtnVal
End Function
```

Then your formula would look like this:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(IsVisible($A$2:$A$11),--($A$2:$A$11=1),--($B$2:$B$11=1),--($C$2:$C$11=1))
```

Comment: Spooky. I had already embarked down this path before checking back in this thread. The UDF I have been writing is almost identical to yours. What is the meaning of the "&" in 1& and 0&?

Comment: It a type declaration character, it forces the literal "1" to the type Long. If you don't put them on your literals VBA will give it the smallest of Integer, Long, or Double. As VB's native type is a long, all statements (such as Redim/For etc.) use long (Hence the 1s). Additionally comparison must go through implicit conversion to same types. So since row height is a long I added it to the 0, so it wouldn't have to undergo an implicit conversion. This is micro-optimization and probably won't make any measurable difference. It's just habit and personal style.The only time it's ...more...

Comment: important to type literals is when you are using Hex or Octal constants and they are unsigned, and so VBA doesn't perform the conversion correctly when the numbers are in certain ranges (2^16th specifically: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/38888). To sum up, you don't really need them I just put them there:)

Comment: Well, I need to do more testing, but this appears to work, and it appears to work fast. The UDF still has to cycle through all the rows to find out if they are hidden or not, but for some reason doing it in the UDF is much faster than doing it in the main procedure with the same nested loop. I am marking this as the solution, and I will put the updated full procedure in a separate post.

Answer (score 0):

This is the full updated code. First the main procedure, then the user defined function.

If anyone can explain why putting the nested loop in a UDF is faster than having it in the main procedure I would greatly appreciated it! Thanks again to Oorang!

I made my version of the IsVisible UDF a bit more flexible. It can use a range passed as a parameter, or if none is passed it uses `Application.Caller`.

```
Private Sub ShowDuplicateRows()

    Dim lngRow As Long
    Dim lngColumn As Long
    Dim strFormula As String

    With Selection

        For lngRow = 1 To .Rows.Count
            If Not .Rows(lngRow).Hidden Then

                strFormula = "SUMPRODUCT(--(ISVISIBLE(" _
                & .Columns(1).Address & "))"
                For lngColumn = 1 To .Columns.Count
                    If Not .Columns(lngColumn).Hidden Then
                        strFormula = strFormula _
                        & ", --(" & .Columns(lngColumn).Address _
                        & " = " & .Cells(lngRow, lngColumn).Address & ")"
                    End If
                Next
                strFormula = strFormula & ")"

                If Evaluate(strFormula) > 1 Then
                    .Rows(lngRow).Font.Color = RGB(255, 0, 0)
                Else
                    .Rows(lngRow).Font.ColorIndex = xlAutomatic
                End If

            End If
        Next lngRow

    End With

End Sub

Public Function IsVisible(Optional ByVal Reference As Range) As Variant

    Dim varArray() As Variant
    Dim lngRow As Long
    Dim lngColumn As Long

    If Reference Is Nothing Then Set Reference = Application.Caller

    With Reference

        ReDim varArray(1 To .Rows.Count, 1 To .Columns.Count)

        For lngRow = 1 To .Rows.Count
            For lngColumn = 1 To .Columns.Count
                varArray(lngRow, lngColumn) _
                = Not .Rows(lngRow).Hidden _
                And Not .Columns(lngColumn).Hidden
            Next lngColumn
        Next lngRow

    End With

    IsVisible = varArray

End Function
```